# How to handle multiple ng-repeats in same table and display data properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Ok, so im kinda stuck with this issue coz data is not displayed properly as it should in my table. I have multiple ng-repeats and i cant organize my table at all.
this is my HTML code for it:

```
  <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="wagon in vm.wagons">
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px; text-align: left;">
                <div>
                    <span class="suggestion-remove-button" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i style="margin-left:25%" class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="vm.removeWagon(wagon, $index)"></i></span><span>{{wagon.name}}</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">
                <span>
                <div ng-repeat="load in vm.suggestion.feeding_1.loads track by $index" class="editable-suggestion-value">
                    <span class="suggestion-remove-button" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="vm.removeLoad($index, 'feeding_1')" ng-hide="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length == 0"></i></span> <data-i18n i18n="_m_f_recipe_load_">Load</data-i18n>&nbsp;{{$index+1}}:&nbsp;<span class="editable-load-value" ng-click="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length > 0 && vm.openEditLoadModal($index, 'feeding_1')">{{load.value}}</span>{{vm.weight}} <span>({{load.wagon_name}})</span>
                </div>
            </span>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">
                <span>
                <div ng-repeat="load in vm.suggestion.feeding_2.loads track by $index" class="editable-suggestion-value">
                    <span class="suggestion-remove-button" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="vm.removeLoad($index, 'feeding_2')" ng-hide="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length == 0"></i></span><data-i18n i18n="_m_f_recipe_load_">Load</data-i18n>&nbsp;{{$index+1}}:&nbsp;<span class="editable-load-value" ng-click="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length > 0 && vm.openEditLoadModal($index, 'feeding_2')">{{load.value}}</span>{{vm.weight}} <span>({{load.wagon_name}})</span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">
                <span>
                <div ng-repeat="load in vm.suggestion.feeding_3.loads track by $index" class="editable-suggestion-value">
                    <span class="suggestion-remove-button" style="margin-right: 10px;"><i class="ion-ios-close-outline" ng-click="vm.removeLoad($index, 'feeding_3')" ng-hide="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length == 0"></i></span> <data-i18n i18n="_m_f_recipe_load_">Load</data-i18n>&nbsp;{{$index+1}}:&nbsp;<span class="editable-load-value" ng-click="vm.wagons && vm.wagons.length > 0 && vm.openEditLoadModal($index, 'feeding_3')">{{load.value}}</span>{{vm.weight}} <span>({{load.wagon_name}})</span>
                </div>
                </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;" class="mixing-suggestion-primary">
                <data-i18n i18n="_m_f_recipe_number_of_loads_">Number of loads</data-i18n>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">{{vm.suggestion.feeding_1.number_of_loads}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">{{vm.suggestion.feeding_2.number_of_loads}}</td>
            <td style="padding: 5px 5px;">{{vm.suggestion.feeding_3.number_of_loads}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

So what i want is to display load for each wagon. And this is how it looks now.. Loads are displayed only for first wagon
[image: table]
If you need some more code, i can provide

Comment: If you can provide wagon load json data that would be helpful

Comment: loads: {value: 454, wagon_id: 57, wagon_name: "W2"};
wagon: {create_date: "2019-09-25T09:10:20Z",herd_id: 630,id: 57,name: "W2",number_of_all: null,selected: true,value: 4540,visible: true,volume: 0,
weight: 4.54}

Comment: If you want to have the loads connected to the wagons in the first column, then you should organize your data such that the load is part of the wagon object in vm.wagons.

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Comment: I started a fiddle here. As I'm missing most of your application I had to do a couple of guesses. https://jsfiddle.net/xfoby59s/ This is just a start. I suggest to play with it to see how it works.